# How to filter product collection using array of attributes and values

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I am trying to filter the productCollection using attribute and values arrays, but it it showing error, here below is my code. Please, let me know how it can be done...

```
$requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParam('requestParams');
$shoppingBy = $requestParams["shoppingBy"];

$attributeCodes = array_keys($shoppingBy);

$productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")
->load($requestParams['categoryId'])
->getProductCollection();

foreach($attributeCodes as $attributeCode) {
    $attributeValue = $shoppingBy[$attributeCode];
    $filter = array('attribute' => $attributeCode, 'in' => $attributeValue);
    $productCollection = $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
}
```

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /var/www/html/eleczo/trunk/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: Have you verified there is an attribute with the code `$attributeCode` in the attribute set used by the products in your ProductCollection? Please, inspect the values of `$attributeCode`, as well as check the attribute sets of all products in `getProductCollection`.